# Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework

I'm working with Adobe Air and PHP with Zend Framework for remoting.

Currently on one particular machine, I am getting the "Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received" error in the first call that the Air app makes to a php function.

I tried running the php files with some debug statements, and those work fine, so its not a problem of php connecting to the database. Also the functions that are called from the flex, are getting called (its getting logged right down to before the last return statement) but the control never returns back to flex. I also confirmed by calling the same functions directly via a php file with the same parameter values and it returns expected values properly. So I am positive it's not an exception due to some php error code.

The entire setup works perfectly on other machines. I don't want to just reinstall everything blindly, since I want to know what setup might be causing this.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: any success on this? i have the same problem...

Comment: Actually I just created the project from scratch and included the existing source files and it started working fine. Not sure what was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

faced the same error while using zend_amf with flex. I am following Richard Bates tutorial VTC Adobe Air And PHP Development

The most helpful hint was in apache logs (you can see once you right click on wamp->Apache->Apache logs).

the latest logs are towards the bottom by default.

It could not find the include paths and resulted in fatal errors when the flex .swf file accessed it.

When accessed from wamp the php files(service and supporting php files) just worked fine.

Apache Error Log Example:

Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../DBConnection.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes;d:\wamp\library;D:\wamp\www\EmployeeDirectory\include\services') in D:\wamp\www\EmployeeDirectory\include\services\EmployeeService.php on line 3, referer: app:/EmployeeDirectory.swf

so either add the path to the concerned files to php.ini include_path or use a constant for file paths.

thanks to Richards any Ways for such a great tutorial :)

Alternately:

Check

the gateway class if you

have set the serive class for zend

include at the first line in gateway.php

$basedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'YourProjectFolderInWamp/';
require($basedir."include/services/YourService.php");

remember to use the zend amf's set class method somewhere..

$server->setClass(new YourService());